# webpack doesn't see files

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "declaration": true
    },
    "files": [
        "sample2-inject/app.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
    ]
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve("./sample2-inject/app.ts"),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve("./dist"),
        filename: "bundle.js",
        library: "home"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {loader: "ts-loader"}
        ]
    },
    watch: true,
    devtool: "eval"
};
```

app.ts:

```
import "es6-shim";
import "reflect-metadata";
import {Container} from "typedi";
```

Errors:

> [0] ./~/typedi/index.js 528 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error] [1]
>   ./~/es6-shim/es6-shim.js 533 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error] [2]
>   ./~/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js 540 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1
>   error]
>
> ERROR in ./~/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js Module build failed: Error:
>   Could not find file:
>   '/home/sesmanovich/www/JQueryPlugins/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js'.
>   at getValidSourceFile
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:81080:23) at
>   Object.getEmitOutput
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:81446:30) at
>   getEmit
>   (/home/sesmanovich/www/JQueryPlugins/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:99:43)
>   at Object.loader
>   (/home/sesmanovich/www/JQueryPlugins/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:27:11)
>   @ ./sample2-inject/app.ts 4:0-27

Comment: `npm i reflect-metadata`?

Comment: installed all subl is open file by path of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your webpack config:

```
    loaders: [
        {loader: "ts-loader"}
    ]
```

Is wrong. You should only use `ts-loader` for `ts/tsx` files.

```
loaders: [ // loaders will work with webpack 1 or 2; but will be renamed "rules" in future
  // all files with a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
  { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
]
```

## More

See readme : https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#configuration